# Retrieval of database values using component other than jtable?

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable, jbutton

is there any way to retrieve database rows using component other than jTable where unique jButtons for each row can added and made to perform specific task?

Currently I'm using the following code... jTable appears in a dialog box

```
public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
            throws SQLException {
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        // names of columns
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println("7");
        for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
            columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
        }
        // data of the table
        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
            }
            data.add(vector);
        }
        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    }

    public void searchb2() throws SQLException {
        this.be_cgpa = be_cg.getText();
        this.maj_proj = Major.getText();
        this.h_percent = hss_percent.getText();
        this.s_percent = sss_percent1.getText();
        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("select name,age,gender,email_id,phone_num,state from resume1 where qualification='be' and be_cgpa>='" + be_cgpa + "'" + "and maj_proj_tech='" + maj_proj + "'" + "and hss_percent>='" + h_percent + "'" + "and sss_percent='" + s_percent + "'");
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel(rs));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
    }
```

Can this code be modified to add jButton in each row?

Comment: The short answer is yes, the long answer is, you're going to have to write it all yourself, there is nothing that is setup to do this out of the box...

Comment: can you please tell me any other way to implement this?

Comment: or any hint for implementing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason you can't use JTable and add a column containing buttons to the table.

See [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for one way to do this. This class expects you to provide an `Action` that is invoked when the button is clicked. All you need to do is add another String of text to the "vector" after you have finished looping through the column data.

Also, use a `PreparedStatement` for your SQL. It is easier to code and understand and less error prone than your current code.

Comment: i still can't get it.. can you write an example code please

Comment: @user3880661, The link does provide example code. I don't know what you don't understand.

Comment: well I tried... but from some other site... but I've a doubt... Can you please answer this ques....  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985009/getting-database-value-on-clicking-jbutton-i-jtable

Comment: `well I tried...` you tried what? Where is your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you tried? Remember when you ask a question we don't have access to your database. So when you try to understand a new concept then use hardcoded data so everybody can test your code.

Answer (score 0):

table button column is definitely the best way of achieving particular cell's value on clicking the corresponding button but seems to be 1 of the hardest thing in jtable.

another approach for implementing the above is enabling cell selection and using list selection model and list selection listener.
On clicking any cell you can get cell's data in a variable.

you can even fix a column and make an ordinary column with text as "button i" where i=row number. and on clicking this cell, you'll get only particular column's data of corresponding row and can even open a new frame or dialog box depending on your coding, this will make it work like a jbutton! (Actually due to fixed column, clicking any cell in that row will perform that task with column number same as fixed column)

Here is a sample code :

```
final JTable table;
    table = new JTable(data, columnNames)
            {
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
        return false;   //Disallow the editing of any cell
    }
};

    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

    ListSelectionModel cellSelectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
    cellSelectionModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

    cellSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
      public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {


        int[] selectedRow = table.getSelectedRows();

        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRow.length; i++) {
            selectedData = (String) table.getValueAt(selectedRow[i],2);
          }
         new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Selected: " + selectedData);
      }
```