# getting database value on clicking jbutton i jtable?

Tags: database, jtable, jbutton

this is my code

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class DisplayResult extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;
        // JDBC driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; // use specific driver for your database
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc";
    // Database credentials
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    static Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

    public DisplayResult() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));


        int i=0;
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
         columnNames.add("column1");
        columnNames.add("column2");
        columnNames.add("column3");
        columnNames.add("Button");

    String query =
                "select city, name, r_no from test";


        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {

                Vector<String> vstring = new Vector<String>();


                 vstring.add(rs.getString("city"));
                vstring.add(rs.getString("name"));
                vstring.add(rs.getString("r_no"));
                vstring.add("Button"+i);
                 vstring.add("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                 i++;
                data.add(vstring);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stmt != null) {
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                  }
            }
        }

      //  final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        final JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.getColumn("Button").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
table.getColumn("Button").setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        if (DEBUG) {
            table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    printDebugData(table);
                }
            });
        }

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    private void printDebugData(JTable table) {
        int numRows = table.getRowCount();
        int numCols = table.getColumnCount();
        javax.swing.table.TableModel model = table.getModel();

        System.out.println("Value of data: ");
        for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
            for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + model.getValueAt(i, j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Database Data");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        DisplayResult newContentPane = new DisplayResult();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
       //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               createAndShowGUI();
            }
       });
    }
}
class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {

    public ButtonRenderer() {
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (isSelected) {
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
        }
        setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
        return this;
    }
}

class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

    protected JButton button;
    private String label;
    private boolean isPushed;

    public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
        super(checkBox);
        button = new JButton();
        button.setOpaque(true);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //x=e.getSource();
                fireEditingStopped();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        if (isSelected) {
            button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
            button.setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }
        label = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
        button.setText(label);
        isPushed = true;
        return button;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        if (isPushed) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button, label + ": Button Action!");
        }
        isPushed = false;
        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        isPushed = false;
        return super.stopCellEditing();
    }

    @Override
    protected void fireEditingStopped() {
        super.fireEditingStopped();
    }
}
```

I've added button to each row and it is performing the action as well
But in the variable "label" I want to get particular value from a database column for a particular database row. Can anyone please tell me how to do  that?

Comment: I have no idea what your question is about. You have already loaded the data from the database into your table so what value are you trying to get? Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) then demonstrates your problem. Remember, we don't have access to your database so the data in the table should be hardcoded. In your last posting (http://stackoverflow.com/q/24976142/131872) you were shown an easy way to write an `Action` that would allow you to access the JTable and TableModel. How does this not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: i want to get particular database value in a dialog box on clicking the button! I wanted an approach to do that!

Comment: So what is the problem? What don't you know how to do. You already have all the data in the table from your intial query, so that shows that you know how to use SQL. You have already crated a JFrame so you should be able to easily create a JDialog. I gave you example code that shows you how to create the Action and add it to the ButtonColumn so you should be able to create the Action that does the above two steps. Where is your `SSCCE`. You should at least be able to display a JDialog with a JLabel in the dialog. Once you do that then you do the DB query. Do one step at a time. Make an effort!